# Android graphics - how to synchronize the list of drawn objects for the onDraw() method

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I'm trying to draw different objects on the canvas in my CustomView. The list of objects to draw is created dynamically outside the view and is passed as a parameter to the list of objects to draw.

I have a customCustom view class that looks something like this:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    // ...
    
    private final List<Shape> shapeToDrawList = new ArrayList();
    
    // ...
    
    public void setShapeToDrawList(@NonNull List<Shape> list) {
            shapeToDrawList.clear();
            shapeToDrawList.addAll(list);
            invalidate();
    }

    public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        shapeToDrawList.forEach(shape -> {
          shape.draw(canvas);
        });
    }
}
```

- method *setShapeToDrawList* does not run in the main thread
- *Shape* - is an object that ensures rendering of the object on the canvas

## Issue

- In the *setShapeToDrawList* method I ***set the list of objects*** and perform *invalidate()*.
- In the *onDraw* method, ***the list is empty***. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried

- lock
- CopyOnWriteArrayList

but so far all my efforts are in vain. Please help me.

## Note:

When I modified the array definition to

```
private final List<Shape> shapeToDrawList = new ArrayList();
```

it is working properly. Can someone please explain to me why?